# Verifiy NTP server update - at start

Tags: esp8266, time

I have function to start an NTP service, right after obtaining wifi connection ( using ESP8266 board ).

from time to time, I get an error saying date and time is`01-01-1970`... which I assume is due to not reaching the server as intended.

A retry counter was added to give few more retries, but somehow I does not do the trick since I never get the expected message `NTP CHECK: #` and retry number ( while get an invalid date ).
I know that `NTP.begin()` returns a bool to describe success/ failure obtaining a NTP server

**EDIT1**: using `NtpClientLib`

How can it be done ?

```cpp
void startNTP() {
        int counter = 0;
        while ( !NTP.begin("pool.ntp.org", 2, true) && counter <=2){
          Serial.print("NTP CHECK: #");
          Serial.println(counter);
          counter +=1;
          delay(1000);
        };
        NTP.setInterval(clockUpdateInt); // in seconds
}
```

Comment: which NTP library are you using? `never get the expected message NTP CHECK: # and retry number` - that suggests that that NTP.begin returns **true**

Comment: if you are using https://github.com/gmag11/NtpClient library, then the only reason begin returns false is if you pass in invalid arguments

Comment: @JaromandaX - I'm using `NtpClientLib`- and YES I know that result is `true` but still date is as noted...

Comment: the point is there's no point in running begin over and over again, since it only returns false if you pass in invalid arguments - as you are passing valid arguments, there's no need to check ... the way I would do it, in the code that relies on valid time, check `NTP.getLastNTPSync()` and skip the code if the result is `0`

Comment: But those are the arguments- which are not invalid

Comment: As I said, they are valid, therefore there's no point in checking if .begin returns true ... it does ... but .begin doesn't return true when the time has been synchronised! it returns true before there's even an attempt to synchronise the time - so you need to check for when the time is synchronised

Answer (score 1):

> Having read the NTPClientLib code, I would say that the first sync is not even attempted for 1 second after `NTP.begin()` is called anyway.

You could do this

```
void startNTP() {
    NTP.begin("pool.ntp.org", 2, true);
    delay(2000); // there seems to be a 1 second delay before first sync will be attempted, delay 2 seconds allows request to be made and received
    int counter = 2;
    while ( !NTP.getLastNtpSync() && counter <=2) {
        Serial.print("NTP CHECK: #");
        Serial.println(counter);
        counter +=1;
        delay(1000);
    };
    NTP.setInterval(clockUpdateInt); // in seconds
}
```

or, you could do this

```
void loop() {
    // code that doesn't rely on valid time
    //
    // lets say this bit of code requires sync'd time
    if (NTP.getLastNtpSync()) {
        // this will only run once NTP has been sync'd at least once
    }
    // more code that doesn't require sync'd time
}
```

Now, you may want to check how long time hasn't been sync'd for in your code and *do something* if it's been too long